# Make UIImageView accessible from all viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

My question is, how can I make it so `redDot` and `wCircle` can be accessed from the Second viewController so they can become hidden or not hidden. They are not connected directly, but you can get to them with different viewControllers.

First viewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var redDot: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var wCircle: UIImageView!
}
```

Second viewController

```
class ProgressViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var rDot: UIImageView!                

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        

        rDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        rDot.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: rDot)            
    }        

    func rdotimageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        wcircle.isHidden = true
        redDot.isHidden = false
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("It worked")
    }
```

[image]

Comment: hmm your question is not really complete! what is the relationship between first and second view controller? Are you using segue? Are you presenting it from Story board? Are they even connected to each other ?

Comment: your question is still the same but I think you have used segue. Please have a look at my answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is a right way but what I would do is have a reference of UIImageView in my second VC and then set that to the imageView of my first VC.

So add these two in your "ProgressViewController"

```
var redDot: UIImageView?
var wCircle: UIImageView?
```

and then in your prepare for segue pass your current UIImageView.

```
let progressViewController = segue.destination as! ProgressViewController
progressViewController.redDot = self.redDot
progressViewController.redDot.wCircle = self.wCircle
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, Can you please upload a picture of your storyboard ?

Comment: I updated with picture. the bottom left is secondViewController and bottom right is progressViewController. the top is the third viewController

Comment: hmm I have never been in this situation but what you might be able to do is initialise your labels in the third VC and then pass reference to the bottom VCs.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding a new member to your second and third view controllers, this member is a closure:

```
var updateFirstViewControllerImageViews: (() -> Void)?
```

Then override prepare for segue method of your `firstViewController`, and set `updateFirstViewControllerImageViews` for each of your second and third view controller like this:

```
secondViewController.updateFirstViewControllerImageViews = { 
    // Update your image views here in the way you want!
}
```

Now, in your second and third view controllers you can use that closure wherever you want like this:

`self.updateFirstViewControllerImageViews?()`